# How to stop VS Code jumping from one thread to another when debugging a multi-threaded Python app?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug a multi-threaded Python application in Visual Studio Code, and it keeps jumping from one thread to another. I'd prefer it to finish the thread it started before jumping to the next. Is that possible? How do the pause buttons on the threads work?

[image: picture of VS Code call stack]

Specifically it's the AWS IoT Python SDK, and the MQTT connection is multi-threaded with callbacks that fire when a subscription topic receives a message. It's somewhat random and frustrating to debug.

I can't be the first person to have this problem, but I can't find any information anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: I am experiencing this issue too. Were you able to solve this? @Sean McCarthy?

Comment: Not really, to be honest. I just kind of got used to it and set lots of break points if I was debugging multi-threaded apps